# Critical section failure

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I successfully used critical sections years ago, but my memory of how it all worked has rather faded. I needed to use them again so I cut and paste some code from one of my old projects and created the following which includes a test to make sure its working as expected:

```
void function_x()
{
    thread t1(modify,  0);
    thread t2(modify,  1);
    thread t3(modify,  2);
    thread t4(modify,  3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}

void modify(int set)
{
    // InitializeCriticalSection(&critsecA); already done early in WinWain()

    // misc code here
    blah blah blah, loops etc.

    EnterCriticalSection(&critsecA); 

    static int set_on_entry = set;

    // do a bunch of work here
    blah blah blah, loops etc.

    if (set_on_entry != set)
    {
        error_report("Thread fail!!");
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&critsecA);
}
```

To my surprise I got the message "Thread fail!!" when I ran the code. I thought this was not possible. Did I forget something?

Comment: `void void modify` ?? Can you post the code for Enter/Leave section ?

Comment: "void void" was a typo - now fixed. When you say post the code - do you mean the "// do a bunch of work here" part? There's quite a lot of it!

Comment: First of all it seems like your critical section is quite large. It shouldn't be, it should be as small as possible or you will not have parallelism between the threads. If you need some shared data, just extract (copy) it locally and then leave the critical section to work on the data. Secondly, your problem is most likely in the parts of the code you don't show us.

Comment: Why should it not be possible? `set_on_entry` is initialized by the first thread that enters the critical section and the other ones have different `set`s.

Comment: What is surprising about this? the static is initialized only once by the first thread, the other 3 just check against a different value and those don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `static int set_on_entry = set;` is only executed once, by the first thread. Then, the other 3 threads will check `if(0 != 1), if(0 != 2), if(0 != 3)` respectively, which will all evaluate to `true` obviously.

If you want to have one `set_on_entry` per thread use `thread_local`:

```
static thread_local int set_on_entry = set;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the static variable, not with your critical section. The static variable initialisation is executed only once, then the assignement is no longer executed.

What you want to write is:

```
static int set_on_entry = 0;//or whatever value, will be overwritten
set_on_entry = set;
```